# The filename, directory name or volume label syntax incorrect

Tags: java

I get the following exception:

> D:\Try\folder\filename_1_06_09_2014_12:46:18.txt (The filename,
>   directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

While using timestamp in renaming filename here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) { 
    String fileName = new SimpleDateFormat("MM_dd_yyyy_hh:mm:ss").format(new Date());
    copyDirectory(new File(sourceLocation, children[i]), new File(targetLocation, files+"_"+fileName+".txt"));
}
```

I can't figure it out where I use invalid characters in windows filename. Any suggestions please?

Comment: here is the full list: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You cannot use colons `:` to create file in Windows. If you absolutely need the timestamp then you could try to add underscores for them as well.

Comment: This was my problem. I changed my format to the following and now my screenshots are correctly named in my Windows directory:                                    java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'_'HHmmss'_'");

Comment: Saved my time... Was searching all other places but this is the rootcause of my issue also... Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Another variant of this is if you accidentally set a prefix to an absolut path. In my case this resulted in something like `data/storageC:/Users/bansg22/data/storage`

Answer (score -2):

Just change root directory name with valid charachters

Answer (score -2):

This problem can also be risen because of the permissions at level security you have at the folder you are trying to open or file you are trying to write.