# Copy SmbFile from one remote network share to another remote network share

Tags: java, jcifs

I try to copy files from one network share to another.

When I run the code it says "failed to copy". But it is able to create the folder structure in the target folder.

That means this folder exists on target share after run:
\DiskStation\OpenKM Import Handled\20200728-132700\Strato\2013

But no file is created. You can see source and target folder in the first exception.

What am I doing wrong? In case it is important. The app runs on windows. The differrent shares are on a Synology Diskstation.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

I use jcifs.smb package for that.

The relevant lines are:

```
    SmbFile targetFolder = getMoveToTargetFile(targetToMoveTo, newDocName, def);
    SmbFile targetFile = new SmbFile(targetFolder, String.format("%s%s",  targetToMoveTo, newDocName));
    
    entry.copyTo(targetFile);
```

The execptions are:

```
jcifs.smb.SmbException: Failed to copy file from [smb://;OpenKM:xxxx@Diskstation/OpenKM Hot Folder/Strato/2013/DRP48646659.pdf] to [smb://;OpenKM:xxxx@Diskstation/OpenKM Import Handled/20200728-132700/Strato/2013/DRP4864665(2).pdf]
at jcifs.smb.SmbCopyUtil.copyFile(SmbCopyUtil.java:186)
at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.copyRecursive(SmbFile.java:1390)
at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.copyTo(SmbFile.java:1441)
at com.engst.test.java_project.App.handleFileEntry(App.java:272)
at com.engst.test.java_project.App.handleDirectoryEntry(App.java:181)
at com.engst.test.java_project.App.handleDirectoryEntry(App.java:194)
at com.engst.test.java_project.App.handleDirectoryEntry(App.java:194)
at com.engst.test.java_project.App.main(App.java:100)

Caused by: jcifs.smb.SmbException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
at jcifs.smb.SmbTransportImpl.checkStatus2(SmbTransportImpl.java:1461)
at jcifs.smb.SmbTransportImpl.checkStatus(SmbTransportImpl.java:1572)
at jcifs.smb.SmbTransportImpl.sendrecv(SmbTransportImpl.java:1027)
at jcifs.smb.SmbTransportImpl.send(SmbTransportImpl.java:1543)
at jcifs.smb.SmbSessionImpl.send(SmbSessionImpl.java:409)
at jcifs.smb.SmbTreeImpl.send(SmbTreeImpl.java:472)
at jcifs.smb.SmbTreeConnection.send0(SmbTreeConnection.java:404)
at jcifs.smb.SmbTreeConnection.send(SmbTreeConnection.java:318)
at jcifs.smb.SmbTreeConnection.send(SmbTreeConnection.java:298)
at jcifs.smb.SmbTreeHandleImpl.send(SmbTreeHandleImpl.java:130)
at jcifs.smb.SmbTreeHandleImpl.send(SmbTreeHandleImpl.java:117)
at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.openUnshared(SmbFile.java:693)
at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.openUnshared(SmbFile.java:655)
at jcifs.smb.SmbCopyUtil.openCopyTargetFile(SmbCopyUtil.java:68)
at jcifs.smb.SmbCopyUtil.copyFile(SmbCopyUtil.java:124)
... 7 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer this .
[The filename, directory name or volume label syntax incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24116311/the-filename-directory-name-or-volume-label-syntax-incorrect)

Maybe directory or filename have invalid character such as white space.
You can try to use english character only.And if that works try challenge abother thing.
Thabk you.

Comment: Unfortunately this was not the issue. I found now a way how it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found now a solution that works for me. I am now getting SmbResourece for the networks shares and based on those I get SmbFile objects to do the copy operation.

I can also omit username and password in my connectString variables.

With that approach I can copy the files.

Feel free to let me know how I can make that smoother or more best practice like.

Thanks.

```
    SmbFile srcFile = null;
    
    try {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.put( "jcifs.smb.client.enableSMB2", "true");
    prop.put( "jcifs.smb.client.disableSMB1", "false");
    prop.put( "jcifs.traceResources", "true" );
    Configuration config = new PropertyConfiguration(prop);  
    
    BaseContext bc = new BaseContext(config);
    
    NtlmPasswordAuthenticator auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthenticator("", "OpenKM", "xxxx");
    CIFSContext ct = bc.withCredentials(auth);
    String connectString = "smb://192.168.10.10/OpenKM Hot Folder/";
    connectString = connectString.replace('\\',  '/');
    SmbResource sr = ct.get(connectString);
    srcFile = new SmbFile(sr, "Strato/2013/DRP46412852.pdf");
    
    
    BaseContext bc2 = new BaseContext(config);
    NtlmPasswordAuthenticator auth2 = new NtlmPasswordAuthenticator("", "OpenKM", "xxxx");
    CIFSContext ct2 = bc2.withCredentials(auth2);
    String connectString2 = "smb://192.168.10.10/OpenKM Import Handled/";
    connectString2 = connectString2.replace('\\',  '/');
    SmbResource sr2 = ct2.get(connectString2);
    SmbFile targetFile = new SmbFile(sr2, "20200728-223352/Strato/2013/paul(2).pdf");
    
    srcFile.copyTo(targetFile);
    } finally {
        srcFile.close();
    }
```